# Add class to unselected item in VueJS 2

Tags: vuejs2

I tried setting an active state whenever I select an item and add an `active` class to it. Now, I wonder how can we get the unselected item and add a specific class to it like `not-active`.

Sample:

```
<img src="/images/icons/thumbup.png"
     @click="setActive('thumbUp')"
     class="thumb-active"
     :class="{ active: isActive('thumbUp') }">

<img src="/images/icons/thumbdown.png" 
     @click="setActive('thumbDown')"
     class="thumb-active"
     :class="{ active: isActive('thumbDown') }">
```

Vue script:

```
export default {
        data() {
            return {
                activeItem: '',
            }
        },
        methods: {
            isActive: function (button) {
                return this.activeItem === button
            },
            setActive: function (button) {
                this.activeItem = button
            }
        },
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very, *very* simply

```
:class="{ active: isActive('state A'), 'not-active': isActive('state B') }"
```

Here's a demo...

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    activeItem: null
  },
  methods: {
    isActive: function (button) {
        return this.activeItem === button
    },
    setActive: function (button) {
        this.activeItem = button
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.not-active {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

button {
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.0/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<button src="/images/icons/thumbup.png"
     @click="setActive('thumbUp')"
     class="thumb-active"
     :class="{ active: isActive('thumbUp'), 'not-active': isActive('thumbDown') }">
     Thumbs Up!
</button>

<button src="/images/icons/thumbdown.png" 
     @click="setActive('thumbDown')"
     class="thumb-active"
     :class="{ active: isActive('thumbDown'), 'not-active': isActive('thumbUp') }">
     Thumbs Down¡
</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, tried it but the `not-active` class is always present. I want it to just add it into the unselected item. It triggers only after a click

Comment: @claudios you aren't literally using "whatever" are you? What defines an item as *"unselected"*?

Comment: I use `thumbUp` and `thumbDown` as parameter. When page loads, the not-active class is present always which is opposite to what I want to achieve

Comment: @claudios not sure what you mean there. You're initialising your component to have an empty value for `activeItem` so of course the `not-active` class is present at first

Comment: Yes, the class `not-active` is present on initialization due to no selected item returned. Now, how can we just add the class after a selection has made?

Comment: @claudios all you have to do then is only apply the class if the `activeItem` is not the default value. See my updated answer

Comment: @claudios actually, it's even easier than that given a binary state. You can just assign the "not-active" class when the *other* state is active. See my updated answer

Comment: Yes Phil. Thanks for this.